# Stripe v9 changes -- metadata

Tags: java, api, stripe-payments, metadata

The new stripe-java v9 has this added functionality:

```
  ChargeCreateParams typedParams = ChargeCreateParams.builder()
      .setAmount(100L)
      .setCurrency("usd")
      .setSource("card_123")
      .build();
```

ChargeCreateParams doesn't have a `setMetadata` option. How can one do that now? I don't see any documentation around this either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a Github issue for this and got a super swift reply. Thought I'd share it here. (as I guess it'll take some time for the documentation to catch up)

You can use either of the following approaches:

```
ChargeCreateParams typedParams = ChargeCreateParams.builder()
      .setAmount(100)
      .setCurrency("usd")
      .setSource("card_123")
      .putMetadata("key1", "value1")
      .putMetadata("key2", "value2")
      .build();
```

or:

```
Map<String, String> metadata = new Map<>();
map.put("key1", "value1");
map.put("key2", "value2");
ChargeCreateParams typedParams = ChargeCreateParams.builder()
      .setAmount(100L)
      .setCurrency("usd")
      .setSource("card_123")
      .putAllMetadata(metadata)
      .build();
```